# configuring maven for windows 7

Tags: maven

I am trying to configure maven 3.0.3 for windows 7. I have it on D drive root. I do like:
environment variable -> system variables ->MAVEN_HOME = D\apache-maven-3.0.3 and system variables -> PATH =  %JAVA_HOME%\BIN;%MAVEN_HOME%\BIN.

```
I want to know if it's configured or there is some problem.
```

when I typed mvn --3.0.3 on command line, it outpts as:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Babar>mvn --3.0.3
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --3.0.3

usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]

Options:
 -am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects required by the
                                        list
 -amd,--also-make-dependents            If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects that depend on
                                        projects on the list
 -B,--batch-mode                        Run in non-interactive (batch)
                                        mode
 -C,--strict-checksums                  Fail the build if checksums don't
                                        match
 -c,--lax-checksums                     Warn if checksums don't match
 -cpu,--check-plugin-updates            Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -D,--define <arg>                      Define a system property
 -e,--errors                            Produce execution error messages
 -emp,--encrypt-master-password <arg>   Encrypt master security password
 -ep,--encrypt-password <arg>           Encrypt server password
 -f,--file <arg>                        Force the use of an alternate POM
                                        file.
 -fae,--fail-at-end                     Only fail the build afterwards;
                                        allow all non-impacted builds to
                                        continue
 -ff,--fail-fast                        Stop at first failure in
                                        reactorized builds
 -fn,--fail-never                       NEVER fail the build, regardless
                                        of project result
 -gs,--global-settings <arg>            Alternate path for the global
                                        settings file
 -h,--help                              Display help information
 -l,--log-file <arg>                    Log file to where all build output
                                        will go.
 -N,--non-recursive                     Do not recurse into sub-projects
 -npr,--no-plugin-registry              Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -npu,--no-plugin-updates               Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -nsu,--no-snapshot-updates             Suppress SNAPSHOT updates
 -o,--offline                           Work offline
 -P,--activate-profiles <arg>           Comma-delimited list of profiles
                                        to activate
 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                        reactor projects to build instead
                                        of all projects. A project can be
                                        specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                        or by its relative path.
 -q,--quiet                             Quiet output - only show errors
 -rf,--resume-from <arg>                Resume reactor from specified
                                        project
 -s,--settings <arg>                    Alternate path for the user
                                        settings file
 -T,--threads <arg>                     Thread count, for instance 2.0C
                                        where C is core multiplied
 -t,--toolchains <arg>                  Alternate path for the user
                                        toolchains file
 -U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for updated
                                        releases and snapshots on remote
                                        repositories
 -up,--update-plugins                   Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -V,--show-version                      Display version information
                                        WITHOUT stopping build
 -v,--version                           Display version information
 -X,--debug                             Produce execution debug output
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\Babar>mvn -3.0.3
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -3.0.3

usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]

Options:
 -am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects required by the
                                        list
 -amd,--also-make-dependents            If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects that depend on
                                        projects on the list
 -B,--batch-mode                        Run in non-interactive (batch)
                                        mode
 -C,--strict-checksums                  Fail the build if checksums don't
                                        match
 -c,--lax-checksums                     Warn if checksums don't match
 -cpu,--check-plugin-updates            Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -D,--define <arg>                      Define a system property
 -e,--errors                            Produce execution error messages
 -emp,--encrypt-master-password <arg>   Encrypt master security password
 -ep,--encrypt-password <arg>           Encrypt server password
 -f,--file <arg>                        Force the use of an alternate POM
                                        file.
 -fae,--fail-at-end                     Only fail the build afterwards;
                                        allow all non-impacted builds to
                                        continue
 -ff,--fail-fast                        Stop at first failure in
                                        reactorized builds
 -fn,--fail-never                       NEVER fail the build, regardless
                                        of project result
 -gs,--global-settings <arg>            Alternate path for the global
                                        settings file
 -h,--help                              Display help information
 -l,--log-file <arg>                    Log file to where all build output
                                        will go.
 -N,--non-recursive                     Do not recurse into sub-projects
 -npr,--no-plugin-registry              Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -npu,--no-plugin-updates               Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -nsu,--no-snapshot-updates             Suppress SNAPSHOT updates
 -o,--offline                           Work offline
 -P,--activate-profiles <arg>           Comma-delimited list of profiles
                                        to activate
 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                        reactor projects to build instead
                                        of all projects. A project can be
                                        specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                        or by its relative path.
 -q,--quiet                             Quiet output - only show errors
 -rf,--resume-from <arg>                Resume reactor from specified
                                        project
 -s,--settings <arg>                    Alternate path for the user
                                        settings file
 -T,--threads <arg>                     Thread count, for instance 2.0C
                                        where C is core multiplied
 -t,--toolchains <arg>                  Alternate path for the user
                                        toolchains file
 -U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for updated
                                        releases and snapshots on remote
                                        repositories
 -up,--update-plugins                   Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -V,--show-version                      Display version information
                                        WITHOUT stopping build
 -v,--version                           Display version information
 -X,--debug                             Produce execution debug output
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\Babar>mvn 3.0.3
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.179s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 17 22:50:38 EET 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/4M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Users\Babar). Please verify you invoked Maven from the co
rrect directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject
Exception
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\Babar>mvn
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.637s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 17 22:55:34 EET 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/4M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid li
fecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id
>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are
: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, p
rocess-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-
sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-
test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-
test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-cle
an, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifie
dException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\Babar>mvn --3.0.3
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --3.0.3

usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]

Options:
 -am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects required by the
                                        list
 -amd,--also-make-dependents            If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects that depend on
                                        projects on the list
 -B,--batch-mode                        Run in non-interactive (batch)
                                        mode
 -C,--strict-checksums                  Fail the build if checksums don't
                                        match
 -c,--lax-checksums                     Warn if checksums don't match
 -cpu,--check-plugin-updates            Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -D,--define <arg>                      Define a system property
 -e,--errors                            Produce execution error messages
 -emp,--encrypt-master-password <arg>   Encrypt master security password
 -ep,--encrypt-password <arg>           Encrypt server password
 -f,--file <arg>                        Force the use of an alternate POM
                                        file.
 -fae,--fail-at-end                     Only fail the build afterwards;
                                        allow all non-impacted builds to
                                        continue
 -ff,--fail-fast                        Stop at first failure in
                                        reactorized builds
 -fn,--fail-never                       NEVER fail the build, regardless
                                        of project result
 -gs,--global-settings <arg>            Alternate path for the global
                                        settings file
 -h,--help                              Display help information
 -l,--log-file <arg>                    Log file to where all build output
                                        will go.
 -N,--non-recursive                     Do not recurse into sub-projects
 -npr,--no-plugin-registry              Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -npu,--no-plugin-updates               Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -nsu,--no-snapshot-updates             Suppress SNAPSHOT updates
 -o,--offline                           Work offline
 -P,--activate-profiles <arg>           Comma-delimited list of profiles
                                        to activate
 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                        reactor projects to build instead
                                        of all projects. A project can be
                                        specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                        or by its relative path.
 -q,--quiet                             Quiet output - only show errors
 -rf,--resume-from <arg>                Resume reactor from specified
                                        project
 -s,--settings <arg>                    Alternate path for the user
                                        settings file
 -T,--threads <arg>                     Thread count, for instance 2.0C
                                        where C is core multiplied
 -t,--toolchains <arg>                  Alternate path for the user
                                        toolchains file
 -U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for updated
                                        releases and snapshots on remote
                                        repositories
 -up,--update-plugins                   Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -V,--show-version                      Display version information
                                        WITHOUT stopping build
 -v,--version                           Display version information
 -X,--debug                             Produce execution debug output
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

While tutorial I am following says It should print out your installed version of Maven, for example:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
Maven home: D:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_25, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
mvn -version
```

To use maven easly it is enough to add its bin folder to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Try `mvn -v` or `mvn --version`.

As can be seen `-v` or `--version` is the *options* parameter to be used (and not the version number itself). If you look the first line of your printout, maven informs you about an unknown option:

> Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

--3.0.3 is not a valid goal so it shows you all possible maven paramenters.

Try:

```
mvn install
```

this should give you an error as well. However it should start downloading some files.
Afterwards your user should have a .m2 folder in his personal directory.

Comment: Actually you won't install anything as you don't have a pom.xml in your current folder. However afterwards you can see if its building up your local repository or not.